# Where do I put this PHP code?

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to get a webpage to show images but it doesn't seem to be working.

here's the code:

```
    <?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
?>
```

If the code should work, where do i put it?
If not, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Put it in `/dev/null/script.php`

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to put this code in a directory that contains a directory named "images". The directory named "images" also needs to have files in a `*.*` name format. There are definitely better ways to do what you're trying to do. Such would be using a database that contains all the images that you want to display.

If that doesn't suit what you want to do, you'd have to be much more descriptive. I have no idea what you want to do and all I'm getting from the code you showed us is to render every file in a directory called "images" as an image.

However, if this point of this post was to simply ask "How do I execute PHP?", please do some searching and never bother us with a question like that.

Another thing @zerkms noticed was that your `for ..` loop starts at iteration 1 (`$i = 1`). This means that a result in the array will be skipped over.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
```

Comment: And you should put this code in a text file with a php extension, for example index.php

Comment: Worth mentioning that: 1. `for` starts with `1` - so something will be lost 2. It will put the current php file as an image to a page as well

Comment: @zerkms It won't put the current PHP file because it's globbing `/images`, but I'll address the `for` loop starting at 1.

Comment: @Nile: oh, right. I missed `images/` and thought it iterates over the current dir

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet iterates over the files in the directory images/ and echos their filenames wrapped in `<img>` tags. Wouldn't you put it where you want the images?

Answer (score 1):

This would go into a PHP file (`images.php` for example) in the parent directory of the `images` folder you are listing the images from. You can also simplify your loop (and correct it, since array indexes should start at `0`, not `1`) by using the following syntax:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("images/*.*") as $file){
    echo '<img src="'.$file.'" alt="random image">&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd think you need a `foreach` instead of a `for` there.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* Lists images in any folder as long as it's inside your $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].
* If it's outside, it's not accessible.
* Returns false and warning or array() like this:
* 
* <code>
* array('/relative/image/path' => '/absolute/image/path');
* </code>
* 
* @param string $Path
* @return array/bool
*/
function ListImageAnywhere($Path){
    // $Path must be a string.
    if(!is_string($Path) or !strlen($Path = trim($Path))){
        trigger_error('$Path must be a non-empty trimmed string.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    // If $Path is file but not folder, get the dirname().
    if(is_file($Path) and !is_dir($Path)){
        $Path = dirname($Path);
    }
    // $Path must be a folder.
    if(!is_dir($Path)){
        trigger_error('$Path folder does not exist.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    // Get the Real path to make sure they are Parent and Child.
    $Path = realpath($Path);
    $DocumentRoot = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    // $Path must be inside $DocumentRoot to make your images accessible.
    if(strpos($Path, $DocumentRoot) !== 0){
        trigger_error('$Path folder does not reside in $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    // Get the Relative URI of the $Path base like: /image
    $RelativePath = substr($Path, strlen($DocumentRoot));
    if(empty($RelativePath)){
        // If empty $DocumentRoot ===  $Path so / will suffice
        $RelativePath = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    // Make sure path starts with / to avoid partial comparison of non-suffixed folder names
    if($RelativePath{0} != DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR){
        trigger_error('$Path folder does not reside in $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    // replace \ with / in relative URI (Windows)
    $RelativePath = str_replace('\\', '/', $RelativePath);
    // List files in folder
    $Files = glob($Path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.*');
    // Keep images (change as you wish)
    $Files = preg_grep('~\\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$~i', $Files);
    // Make sure these are files and not folders named like images
    $Files = array_filter($Files, 'is_file');
    // No images found?!
    if(empty($Files)){
        return array(); // Empty array() is still a success
    }
    // Prepare images container
    $Images = array();
    // Loop paths and build Relative URIs
    foreach($Files as $File){
        $Images[$RelativePath.'/'.basename($File)] = $File;
    }
    // Done :)
    return $Images; // Easy-peasy, general solution!
}

// SAMPLE CODE COMES HERE
// If we have images...
if($Images = ListImageAnywhere(__FILE__)){ // <- works with __DIR__ or __FILE__
    // ... loop them...
    foreach($Images as $Relative => $Absolute){
        // ... and print IMG tags.
        echo '<img src="', $Relative, '" >', PHP_EOL;
    }
}elseif($Images === false){
    // Error
}else{
    // No error but no images
}
```

**Try this on for size.** Comments are self explanatory.